# Not committed data to into a git repository

Tags: git, github, repository, addition, commit

I am trying to add some files from a server to a git repository. I am adding and committing the files, but when I push the files, no new files are in location. The following is the log information.

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   model0001_merged.out
    new file:   model0002_merged.out
    new file:   model0003_merged.out
    new file:   model0004_merged.out
    new file:   model0005_merged.out
    new file:   model0006_merged.out
    new file:   model0007_merged.out
    new file:   model0008_merged.out
    new file:   model0009_merged.out
    new file:   model0010_merged.out
    new file:   model0011_merged.out
    new file:   model0012_merged.out
    new file:   model0013_merged.out
    new file:   model0014_merged.out
    new file:   model0015_merged.out
    new file:   model0016_merged.out
    new file:   model0017_merged.out
    new file:   model0018_merged.out
    new file:   model0019_merged.out

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    ../models/materials.in
    modified:   ../run_batch.sh
```

when I push the data, I am receiving the following msg:

```
Username for https://github.com: ***
Password for https://***@github.com: 
Everything up-to-date
```

May you let me know, how I can push the data to the repository?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot push *files*, you can only push *commits*. (But each commit *contains* files, so pushing a whole commit does the trick. In fact, every commit contains *all* of its files, as a snapshot.)

Comment: @Ehs You did accept the right answer before. What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you need to commit the changes before you can push them, here's how you can do it:

1. Stage the files: run `git add .` which will add everything that either changed or it's new, if you'd like to add only certain files you can use `git add <file_path>` or `git add <folder_path>`
2. After staging the files you need to commit them, you can do so by using:

   - `git commit -m "commit message"`
   - `git commit` which will open an editor(generally vim or nano) and allow you to write the commit message

Only after those 2 steps above you can push your code to the repository.

Comment: The files are already staged, since the status shows "to be committed". And I did mention the commit in my answer.

Comment: Agreed @VonC, however there are some changes that are not staged for the commit, my rationale was that maybe he wanted to push that as well.

Comment: This is about *new* files not present on the remote side. What is not added are deletion or modifications.

Answer (score 2):

If those changes are "to be committed", you should... commit them.

```
git commit -m "add files"
```

Then, and only then the push would actually push something.

Adding files (to the staging area) is not enough: [add *and* commit](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/#add).

Answer (score 1):

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'your commit'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it